# New to Spring MVC: Is an html file being created on the fly here?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am looking at the Spring-Petclinic sample code which uses Spring MVC to display and update/create pet owners, etc. I am confused by the following code fragment in a JSP file:

```
<spring:url value="/owners.html" var="formUrl"/>
<form:form modelAttribute="owner" action="${fn:escapeXml(formUrl)}" method="get" class="form-horizontal"
           id="search-owner-form">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group" id="lastName">
            <label class="control-label">Last name </label>
            <form:input path="lastName" size="30" maxlength="80"/>
            <span class="help-inline"><form:errors path="*"/></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit">Find owner</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form:form>
```

I am wondering if this is trying to create a new file called owners.html because I can't find such a file anywhere in the existing files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. The [JSP tag `<spring:url>`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring.tld.url) is used to define an attribute (named `formUrl` here) referencing an url (which is `/<context-path>/owners.html` here).

Comment: Does this mean that owners.html exists already? Because the reason I asked if the file is being dynamically created is I can find no such file.

Comment: The whole point of Spring MVC is to create a web application. In a web application, pages are not static files. They're dynamically generated. /owners.html is the path of a controller, which is used to dynamically generate a HTML page.

Comment: I think that's the answer: the OwnerController is indeed creating someplace owners.html. But I am not seeing where in the code this is occurring.

Comment: Wait: Is owners.html not an actual file but simply a way of reaching the associated method in the controller? If that is so, why does it have to be owners.html and not simply owners?

Comment: Read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match

Comment: I read the documentation. Still not clear to me whether an html page is generated and if so what it contents are or if it is just a way to invoke the correct method in the Controller.

Comment: I said to you that this was generated an URL pointing to a controller. I quote: */owners.html is the path of a controller, which is used to dynamically generate a HTML page.* Then you asked why not just `/orders`, and I pointed you to the section of the doc explaining that the /orders mapping also matched /orders.html. Not sure what you need more.

Answer (score 0):

No, it just generates the url poining to that action. In this case the action name is owners.html, look inside controller and you will find it.

Answer (score 0):

JSPs are an HTML templating solution.  Here is how it works:

1. You write a JSP, preferably using only tags and not scriptlet code, and put it in your WAR.
2. The servlet/JSP engine reads the JSP when you first request its URL, parses it into an abstract syntax tree, and generates Java source.
3. The servlet/JSP engine compiles the Java source into a .class file, which it then invokes every time it receives a request at that URL.
4. The compiled JSP dynamically merges data into an output stream that is the HTML sent to the browser on request.

So you may find a generated .java or .class file if you know where to look and have asked that it be saved appropriately, but the HTML only exists on the wire from the server to the client.